# Difficulty shading in feasible area on plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am having difficulties setting the maximum and minimum values to shade the feasible region. Please take a look at my code and let me know where I went wrong, thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''
Let x = Square Tables and y = Round Tables

Minimize: z = 40x + 60y
Subject to: x + y >= 5 or y1 = 5 - x BLUE
        x + y <= 10 or y2 = 10 - x ORANGE
        x >= y + 3 or y3 = x - 3 GREEN
'''

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y1 = 5 - x
y2 = 10 - x
y3 = x - 3

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
plt.xlim((0, 12))
plt.ylim((0, 12))
plt.xlabel(r'$Square Tables$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Round Tables$')

y4 = np.minimum(y1, y2)
y5 = np.maximum(y1, y3)
plt.fill_between(x, y4, y5, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y1 = 5 - x
y2 = 10 - x
y3 = x - 3

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot(x, y3)
plt.xlim((0, 12))
plt.ylim((0, 12))
plt.xlabel(r'$Square Tables$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Round Tables$')
y5 = np.minimum(y2, y3)
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y5,where=y5 >= y1, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to determine the actual minimum values using Python and that plot? I can do it by hand, just interested to see what code I would use to minimize my cost...

Comment: @Gru26 You need to use an optimization routine to solve optimization problems. There are many python packages for this purpose. `scipy.optimize` is a good place to start.